# Drop down boxes and radio buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a drop down box that has different values when each value is chosen it changes the values for each of the radio buttons but I want to make it so when when you chose an option for the radio button it keeps that selection in the drop down box value and can't influence any of the other values of the drop down box.

It's for AFL tipping if that helps for any clarification as it is a bit hard to explain and my code is reasonably long. I've grabbed some of the main code parts but I may have left some out that would help so just ask if you need more.

```
variable = StringVar()

round_change = ttk.Combobox(root, state = "readonly", textvariable = variable, values = ['Round 1', 'Round 2'])

def notify (event):
    a = variable.get()
    if a == "Round 1":
        round_games(round_1)
    elif a == "Round 2":
        round_games(round_2)

round_change.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", notify)

def round_games(list):
    tip_1_0 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text = list[0] + "\n" + list[1], width = 13, variable = 1, value = 1)
    tip_1_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text = list[2] + "\n" + list[3], width = 13, variable = 1, value = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Combobox by setting its state to disabled.

```
def click_radio():
    round_change.state(['disabled'])
    round_change.pack()

tip_1_0 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text = list[0] + "\n" + list[1], width = 13, variable = 1, value = 1, command=click_radio)
```

btw to unset the state, you need to call round_change.state(['!disabled'])